# Hide My Account dropdown menu

Tags: magento2, php, login, header

I tried to hide the My Account menu from the dropdown when variable in my session is 0. I already could save my variable to the session, but i can't find the phtml to hide the My Account menu in top dropdown. Which file that generate the header?

Comment: `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml:10`

Comment: There is no phtml for the header?

Comment: `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/navigation.phtml`